# I'm banned after a well-received question?

Tags: support, post-ban, user-accounts

My last question was this one: [To show the difference between system VMs and JVMs](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/403264/to-show-the-difference-between-system-vms-and-jvms).

It was upvoted 3 times, though currently it's only 2. The answer is upvoted 3 times as well. The question isn't closed and isn't a duplicate.

And now, after this question, I'm banned. I wasn't banned *before* asking this question (which was good received), but I'm banned *after* it.

> You have reached your question limit

This is really weird.

And here is the statistics of all my questions, 4 years:

```
Votes | Answers | Date
2     | 1       | Jan 2020
0     | 3       | Nov 2019
0     | 2       | Sep 2019
2     | 1       | Sep 2019
-1    | 1       | Apr 2016
```

Not great, but not terrible. There were 1 or 2 another downvoted questions; I removed them long time ago. Again, doesn't looks as something really bad. I'm not a flooder: as you see, the questions aren't frequent.

Are you sure that such statistics is really so bad to ban someone? Not going to start a flame.

Comment: Did you ask more questions on this site which don't show up in the stats since they were deleted?

Comment: If I recall correctly, there were 2 such questions, I deleted them long time ago. I have reflected it in my last edit, right after your comment.

Comment: Until a mod shows up to give you a more specific answer, maybe this [older meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) may be useful.

Comment: what question did you want to ask?

Comment: banned users are allowed to ask one question in six months so it is possible that you _were_ banned prior to asking but system allowed to ask that one because previous was asked more than 6 months ago